# Writing and reading a file without fseek

Tags: c, embedded

I have some embedded code, that is writing data to a file in one task and reading data from the same file in another task. The writer is faster than the reader, so the reader will first reach end-of-file after the writer has completed.

```
WRITER TASK:
fseek(f, 0, SEEK_END);
fwrite(...)

READER TASK:
fseek(f, rdpos, SEEK_SET);
rdpos += fread(...)
```

Currently the code logic works, but it is too slow.
The fseek calls is taking too long time, especially when the file gets large.

Is there another way of writing and reading a file simultaneously ?

EDIT: I can see this question is probably needs some more info.
The system is a ESP32, so the memory is relative limited, and the file is located on an sdcard and the file size is up to 100Mbyte.
I have tried to open the file two times, like:

```
fwr = fopen(filename, "w+");
...
frd = fopen(filename, "r");
```

Then fwrite(..., fwr) and fread(..., frd), but the read data is bogus.

EDIT2:
The data being stored is audio, we want the audio to be stored fast, but simultaneously being able to start playing the audio.
The audio output codec has a limited buffer, so to prevent this buffer from running empty, we need a low read time. The isolated write and read times are ok, but when during seek, the time gets too high.

EDIT3:
The write speed is about 250Kbyte/s, and the read speed is 16Kbyte/s.

Comment: Are you closing and re-opening the file?  You shouldn't need to do any `fseek` here.

Comment: Is this an embedded implementation of multithreading or are the writer and reader tasks being called in a loop? Can you post your actual code instead of the pseudo?

Comment: Post details about your system, too.  Maybe there are ways to pass the data directly via RAM and leave the disk IO out of the problem - that's probably what's slowing you down - `fseek()` shouldn't take too long as it's (probably! - which is why we need details...) just changing a file offset value in memory somewhere.

Comment: Why is it a problem that the reader is slower? That ss=hould make things easier, since it doesn't have to worry about reaching EOF and then waiting for the writer to add more.

Comment: Are you using the same `FILE*` pointer in both tasks? Try using a different file pointer, then they'll each keep their own position in the file and you don't need `fseek()`. If you use the same pointer, you need mutual exclusion.

Comment: I am using a mutex to protect the file access.

Comment: If the reader is lagging behind the writer, there won't be any "real time" involved in what the reader is doing... Can the project simply gather its 100Mb of data (writing) and process it after the fact? SD cards want to _stream_ data and don't like jumping from one location to another...

Comment: It seems to me that you need a producer-consumer semaphore model, but I still don't think you've given us enough information to understand what exactly is going wrong

Comment: The data being stored is audio, we want the audio to be stored fast, but simultaneously being able to start playing the audio.

Comment: The audio output codec has a limited buffer, so to prevent this buffer from running empty, we need a low read time. The isolated write and read times are ok, but when during seek, the time gets too high.

Comment: Suggestion: a "ringbuffer"... The writer should have enough slack to also copy blocks to a ringbuffer that can be consumed by the reader (instead of file access). Balancing the "chase me" speeds/sizes of write/read would reduce the frequency of 'glitches' when the writer may catch-up to the reader.

Comment: @Fe2O3 Yes, maybe a fallback solution. But that would limit the write speed to the read speed. The write speed is about 250Kbyte/s, and the read speed is 16Kbyte/s.

Comment: Does your embedded environment support the `pipe()` call?  It sounds like having writer send the audio directly to the reader over a pipe (or a `socketpair()`, or similar) might be more efficient than trying to use the filesystem as your intemediary, since in the latter case your performance might be limited by the I/O performance of the (relatively slow) SD card in some cases.

Comment: If "reading" is limited to 16Kb/s, you're not getting CD quality output of the simultaneous passthrough. You may want to work with the numbers and think about the design.

Comment: Normally SD card write is slower than read, and 16K is extraordinarily slow, even for and SPI interface implementation.  Something else is wrong here I suspect unless you can explain that.  Which seek is slow?  Why use w+ then seek to the end?  It creates an empty file.  It is hard to see what you are doing from isolated fragments and a prose description.  Much easier to post the code, or at least  complete code that exhibits the same issue.

Comment: Please _edit_ your _question_ and post your entire/representative code in a _single_ code block. Also, what OS are you using (e.g. linux, FreeRtos, bare metal, etc.)? What are the [audio] devices in question? What do you want to do? (e.g.) "I want to read audio from an input device, save it to a file, and, simultaneously play the audio to an output device" Seems easy, but, if you're using `fseek`, you're already going down the wrong road. If you're trying to use a _file_ to communicate between tasks this is problematic. A pipe, socketpair, SysV IPC, ring buffer, etc. are better approaches.

Comment: @JakobJ For "fwrite(..., fwr) and fread(..., frd)", better to open file in binary mode.

Comment: Does your target system support memory-mapped files?